# Delete app permanently from App stores - iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios

I am able to "Remove from sale" in itunes and unpublished in google play for one of my apps. Now, i am trying to delete them permanently.

iOS:
I have read that i can find a "Delete app" button on the app details page, but i cannot see it. Its been 30 min that i removed the app from sale. Do i have to wait a while to see the "Delete app" button OR am i missing anything.

Android:
When i clicked unpublished for my app, it gave me a message saying this will not delete the app. And i could not find any information on how to delete it. 
Is there a way to delete the app from play store permanently.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: "Is there a way to delete the app from play store permanently" -- AFAIK, no. The app remains available to anyone who had it previously.

Comment: Ok, since the alert said this will not delete the app, i was hoping there is another way to delete it. Thank you for the clarification. Do you have idea about iOS app delete?

Comment: Sorry, I am not an iOS developer.

Comment: You cannot delete an app from the App Store either. You can remove it from sale but it remains available to previous purchasers. At some point in the future it may become unavailable due to compatibility; e.g. iOS 11 dropped support for 32 bit apps, so users who have upgraded to iOS 11 can no longer installs apps that have not been updated to 64 bit

Comment: Thankyou for the information Paul. I found that with iOS, in itunes connect we can actually delete the app. But it is not available for everyone. There are some conditions for the "Delete App" button to show up in app details.

Answer (score 0):

There is no any way to delete app from google play store once it live on play store you are not able to delete that application from play store because google remember all package names and each package name is unique.but you can unpublish it from play store.